# Null pointer Zxing Scanner

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having some real trouble trying to fix my null pointer error.
I am trying to implement the Zxing Scanner from a Fragment in my app, but I am getting the following error.

**Error**

```
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: app.rory.menu, PID: 4123
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView.startCamera()' on a null object reference
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.rory.pocket_chef.Fragments.scan_Foods_Fragment.onCreateView(scan_Foods_Fragment.java:35)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-20 19:17:39.249 4123-4123/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-20 19:17:39.274 782-2968/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity app.rory.menu/app.rory.pocket_chef.MyActivity
```

I followed this simple tutorial (http://d-codepages.com/barcode-scanner-android-example/), but running into the Null Pointer Error.
Should I take a different approach, if I am launching from a Fragment?

**Fragment From Where I am trying to launch Scanner**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;

import app.rory.slidemenu.R;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

/**
 * Created by Rory on 10/22/2014.
 */



public class scan_Foods_Fragment extends Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;

    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_foods_layout, container, false);
        //return rootview;

        scannerView = (ZXingScannerView) container.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
        scannerView.startCamera(); //error on this line
        scannerView.setResultHandler(this);

        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(com.google.zxing.Result result) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alert.setTitle(result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        alert.setMessage(result.getText());
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

**XML File for Fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scanner_view"
        />

    <!--<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/scanFoods"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error here:

```
scannerView = (ZXingScannerView) container.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
```

It must be

```
scannerView = (ZXingScannerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
```